# create log file from bat script in one line

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging

i have script bat file for move file from one folder to each other folder and create the log file.
the script like this :

```
Copy /y c:\temp\temp1\* c:\temp\temp2\ >>c:\temp\makelog.txt
echo %Date% >>c:\temp\makelog.txt %Time% >>c:\temp\makelog.txt
```

and ouput log like this

```
c:\temp\temp1\test.jpg
    1 file(s) copied.
03-Nov-17  10:41:35.52
```

i hope i can create output like this :

```
c:\temp\temp1\test.jpg | 1 file(s) copied. | 03-Nov-17  10:41:35.52
```

any one help me?

thank you so much.

Comment: You would need to use a `FOR /F` command to capture the output of the `COPY` command.  But you also have to take into consideration if it copies more than one file the output will be completely different.

Comment: where i must put a FOR /F code in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, this is only going to work if you are copying a single file.  If the wildcard finds more than one file then this code will not work.

This is how you can do it in one line from the cmd prompt.

```
cmd /V:ON /C "(FOR /F "Tokens=* delims= " %G IN ('Copy /y c:\temp\temp1\* c:\temp\temp2\') DO @((IF DEFINED LINE1 SET "LINE2=%G")&(IF NOT DEFINED LINE1 SET "LINE1=%G"))) &ECHO !LINE1! ^| !LINE2! ^| %date% %time%"
```

This is how you would do it from a batch file.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "Tokens=* delims= " %%G IN ('Copy /y c:\temp\temp1\* c:\temp\temp2\') DO (
    IF DEFINED LINE1 SET "LINE2=%%G"
    IF NOT DEFINED LINE1 SET "LINE1=%%G"
)
ECHO %LINE1% ^| %LINE2% ^| %date% %time%
pause
```